# VS2013 c++: Auto-Parallelization a loop with fortran code inside

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, parallel-processing, fortran

I want to use the VS2013 Auto-Parallelization feature to parallel a loop in C++.

However, inside the loop, there is a call to a fortran function (pre-compiled in fortran). Will auto-parallelization work on this loop?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of parallelism? ILP or SPMD?

Comment: I think it's ILP, I am trying to parallelize a for loop

Comment: Then forget about it. Any function call will prevent compiler doing any ILP optimization. SIMD won't work, either. OpenMP may still work, maybe.